# Problem in installin Piglit

Tags: nvidia

I have cloned this repository git clone `git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/piglit`.
I am currently facing an error on cmake command

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:232 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPythonSix.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "PythonSix", but CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PythonSix"
  (requested version 1.5.2) with any of the following names:
    PythonSixConfig.cmake
    pythonsix-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "PythonSix" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "PythonSix_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "PythonSix" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```